# Horizontal content alignment with JavaScript over several cards

Tags: javascript, html, alignment

I am currently struggling to find a solution to align
a specified element between several cards. The lowest
offset (means position) should be the basis for the
other 'elements'. Thus are aligned by inline-styles then.

```js
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
const arr = [];
var x; //8px
const yPosC = [];

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  let yPosCard = cards[i].offsetTop;
  let rating = cards[i].querySelectorAll(".x");
  let yPosRating = rating[0].offsetTop;
  yPosC.push([yPosCard, yPosRating]);
  if (yPosCard != x) {
    x = cards[i].offsetTop;
  } else {
    x = cards[0].offsetTop;
  }
}

yPosC.forEach(function(key) {
  //console.dir(key[0]); // Rows
  //console.dir(key[1]); // Columns
  
  if (x === key[0]) {
    // Match values for first line
    console.log("woot");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: ;
  grid-template-areas: ". . . .";
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.card {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.x {
  background: red;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.x.y {
  background: green;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="card">One
    <div class="x">Line</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">two
    <div class="x">Line</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">three
    <div class="x">Line</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">four
    <div class="x y">Line</div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="card">
    <div class="x">Wrapped</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe I just need a first start? I tried to build arrays
from the offsetTop given by the cards itself and 'element'.
But what happens then ?
To fiddle around and to illustrate the 'task'.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far as a minimal complete verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: An image of what you are trying to accomplish might help a lot.